# Where do French departments in the US posts jobs?

Tags: united-states, job-search, linguistics

I'm near the end of my PhD and so going on the job market for posts in academia. I'm in linguistics, but I specialize in French. My chair is familiar with where linguistics departments post jobs openings, but neither of us are sure of where French departments (who may still hire some linguists) typically advertise when they have job openings since they'd be unlikely to use the linguistics-specific sites. What are the top 3 or so places to find openings in French departments?

(I'm also not looking to leave the US, so I'm looking for French departments in the US specifically.)

Comment: Be aware that departments that teach French might not have that in their names. For example, at my school, the relevant department is "Romance Languages and Literature".

Answer (score 4):

Here is the MLA Jobs List: https://joblist.mla.org/#languages
You can search by language.